# Div height 0px but with images inside?

Tags: html, css

I've had a look for similar questions and tried removing the position attribute but unfortunatley that didn't work.

I have a container with 2 divs inside, and both those divs contain one image each. The images display correctly but the overall container has a height of 0px. Here is an image with the developer console open: https://gyazo.com/277d635619eb80d2d3f63a1c28c80314
[image]
This happened after trying to make the images responsive with width: 100%; and height: auto;

```css
    #landing-images {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        border: solid 2px black;
    }
    
    .leftLanding {
        /*position: relative;*/
        width: 80%;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .rightLanding {
        /*position: relative;*/
        width: 80%;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .landingImage {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="landing-images">
     <div class="leftLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/57/WDF_1035782.png">
     </div>
     <div class="rightLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/57/WDF_1035782.png">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @karimyafi If the height is auto why doesn't it equal the height of its content? Or 'How do I make the height equal to its content'?

Comment: Hide overflow :)

Comment: overflow: hidden

Comment: floating the child element removes desired behaviour of parent from the document flow and the parent will collapse so you just need to add overflow property as I stated in my answer.

Comment: It is always a good practice to clear the wrapper elements that has floating elements inside it.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Displaying the images as a background-image via css gives you more control of the image-position and scaling than an img tag can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add.

`overflow:auto;` to `#landing-images`.

So, **Your CSS** will be like,

```
#landing-images {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
```

Because floating the child element removes it from the document flow and the parent will collapse. By adding the overflow rule, the desired behavior is restored.

Comment: Thanks @Chirag I'll accept in 3 minutes.On a side note, do you know how to remove the blank space between the images? Here's an image, you can see it just above and below the image https://gyazo.com/a0920678f425359edfc28d5fa61a0fe2

Comment: @EthanBristow is it the image after implementing my advice.? and all other CSS is as it is right.?

Comment: yeah, nothing else has changed

Comment: add `display: block;` to `landingImage` because images are inline elements by default. `display:block;` removes the gap.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the float attributes, use display: block and margin instead.

```css
#landing-images {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: solid 2px black;
    position:relative;
}

.leftLanding {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    display:block;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.rightLanding {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left:auto;
}

.landingImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing-images">
     <div class="leftLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/d2b06305-f201-4127-8eb7-7410bcc0de02/2d6c2415-2b8c-430c-87a4-c516409d8488.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="rightLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/animals/pictures/mammals/g/gray-wolf/gray-wolf_01.ngsversion.1484679603276.JPG">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must **clear the wrapper** whenever there is a floating element inside it.

```css
    #landing-images {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        border: solid 2px black;
    }
    
    .leftLanding {
        /*position: relative;*/
        width: 80%;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .rightLanding {
        /*position: relative;*/
        width: 80%;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .landingImage {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .clearfix::after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="landing-images" class="clearfix">
     <div class="leftLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/57/WDF_1035782.png">
     </div>
     <div class="rightLanding">
         <img class="landingImage" src="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/57/WDF_1035782.png">
     </div>
 </div>
```

I always use the standard clearfix class with the following style:

```
    .clearfix::after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
    }
```

So, always have such a class on your global CSS. And add this class to all the wrappers which has floating elements inside it.

Read more about clearfix concept at:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/